# Spring Integration Service Activator Without Output Channel

Tags: java, spring

In my code I have a inbound adapter channel and a service activator I want not to connect service activator with out bound channel ,

Code I am using

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
        directory="E:/usmandata/logs/input" filter="onlyLogFiles"
        auto-startup="true">
        <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000" />
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="filesIn"  ref="handler" />
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the docs , simply make it as void return type or set it to nullChannel

> If the method returns a result and no "output-channel" is defined, the framework will then check the request Message’s replyChannel header value. If that value is available, it will then check its type. If it is a MessageChannel, the reply message will be sent to that channel. If it is a String, then the endpoint will attempt to resolve the channel name to a channel instance. If the channel cannot be resolved, then a DestinationResolutionException will be thrown. It it can be resolved, the Message will be sent there. If the request Message doesn’t have replyChannel header and and the reply object is a Message, its replyChannel header is consulted for a target destination. This is the technique used for Request Reply messaging in Spring Integration, and it is also an example of the Return Address pattern.
>
> If your method returns a result, and you want to discard it and end the flow, you should configure the output-channel to send to a NullChannel. For convenience, the framework registers one with the name nullChannel. See Section 4.1.6, “Special Channels” for more information.
>
> The Service Activator is one of those components that is not required to produce a reply message. If your method returns null or has a void return type, the Service Activator exits after the method invocation, without any signals. This behavior can be controlled by the AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.requiresReply option, also exposed as requires-reply when configuring with the XML namespace. If the flag is set to true and the method returns null, a ReplyRequiredException is thrown.